# Navbar aumenta de tamaño al hacer clic en un dropdown, en dispositivos pequeños

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de agregar un dropdown a mi navbar en bootstrap 5; este es mi navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-app-name" href="#">Inicio</a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" id="navbar-list-ul">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Y para el dropdown, debido a que cuando le daba click la página se hacía más grande, decidí agregarle estos estilos css para evitar eso:

```
#navbar-list-ul
{
    margin-right: 60px;
}
```

Hasta ahí todo va bien, pero si hago la página mas pequeña, simulando un teléfono, al darle click al navbar el navbar se "deforma" por llamarlo de alguna forma, haciendo el navbar verse de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo evitar que el navbar se vea como la imagen anteriormente agregada, y que se vea un poco más como el navbar de laravel5 (por dar algún ejemplo)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En **bootstrap 5** hay una clase para evitar el problema que tienes, que debes aplicar conjuntamente con `dropdown-menu` sin necesidad de editar ni crear ningun estilo nuevo.

Se llama `dropdown-menu-end` y en este enlace lo explican: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment

> Add .dropdown-menu-end to a .dropdown-menu to right align the dropdown
> menu. Directions are mirrored when using Bootstrap in RTL, meaning
> .dropdown-menu-end will appear on the left side.

Por lo tanto, elimina el estilo CSS que has aplicado y modifica esto:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
```

por esto:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
```

Aquí te dejo un snippet para que lo compruebes:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" id="navbar-app-name" href="#">Inicio</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0" id="navbar-list-ul">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

En cuanto al problema de la página pequeña, tienes dos posibles opciones.

1. Usar `navbar-expand` en lugar de `navbar-expand-md` en el elemento `nav`. Expicado aquí: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors
2. Colapsar el menú usando un botón con la clase `navbar-toggler` a continuación del `navbar-brand` y encerrando el resto del *nav* en un *div* con las clases `collapse navbar-collapse`.  Si miras el snippet verás que también lo acabo de poner. Y también aparece en la [documentación de bootstrap 5 relativa a los navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#supported-content) donde encontrarás más información.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero el problema sigue ya que si la pantalla la hago pequeña aún se deforma el navbar, ¿cómo puedo evitar eso? De todas formas gracias :)

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía Acabo de agregar la solución de bootstrap para los casos de páginas pequeñas. Seguramente no será lo que quieres, pero lo habitual es hacerlo así.

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía: Vuelve a mirar mi respuesta, al final veo que lo de la página pequeña si que se puede hacer como tu quieres (más o menos) cambiando `navbar-expand-md` por `navbar-expand` (cosa que no sabia hasta ahora).

Comment: Muchas gracias, con las soluciones que me diste ya funcionó :)

Comment: Perfecto :-) Me alegro